# Base of subspace $\textbf{W} = \lbrace f \in V : f(\pi)=0\rbrace$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In space of real functions we have subspace $\textbf{V}$ dedicated by set $V = \langle 1,x,\cos x,\sin x \rangle$ and its subspace $\textbf{W}$ dedicated by set $W =  \lbrace f \in V : f(\pi)=0\rbrace$.

I need to find base of space $\textbf{W}$

Comment: You are pretty new to MathSE, but you should still know the following. You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Comment: this is not my homework, I'm not cheater. I'm just preparing for exam and I found this problem in textbook and now'm lost :-(

Comment: You should make that clear in your main question. Also, as I said, tell us just *where* you are stuck. What part of this question *can* you do? You also have an excellent hint from Henning Makholm. What have you been able to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You already have a basis for $\mathbf V$ (though if you don't already know that $V$ is linearly independent, you'd need to show that before you can say for sure that $V$ is a basis for $\mathbf V$), so you can reduce the problems to working in that basis. You also know (hopefully) that
$$ (a\cdot 1+bx+c\cos x+d\sin x)(\pi) = a+b\pi-c $$
So all you need to do is to find a basis for the solution space for the equation
$$ a+\pi b-c+0d = 0 $$
and then map those basis vectors back to actual functions using your basis for $\mathbf V$.